# Tic Tac Toe game wont loop+ or execute rules correctly

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Basically I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game between 2 human players as a beginner task. I'm running into 2 problems when I run the program in the console. The first problem being that the loop I've have set up so players can take multiple goes one after the other is only letting each player have only one go. Another problem is I have a set of rules set up so that if you get 3 in a row the game will finish. The problem is that the game is saying 'game' over after every go.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int SIDE = 3;
        char[][] grid = new char[SIDE][SIDE];
        for (int row = 0; row < SIDE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < SIDE; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = '_';
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < SIDE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < SIDE; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%3c", grid[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%n");
        }
        boolean playing = true;
        while (playing) {
            System.out.println("Player1: Please enter coordinates for your move");
```

Comment: Both your methods start out by ceating a new grid, so `GameOver()` correctly sees the same (empty) value in all directions. Try 1) passing the game grid as parameter or 2) put the game grid one level up so both methods can access it. (and please indent your code)

Answer (score 1):

The GameOver method is creating a new grid when called. So when checking values in rows, columns, and diagonals, it is finding that the values are the same as they are all empty. Give the GameOver method a new parameter which takes the grid and use that. Be careful with this though, as some rows and columns will now all have an "_" as it's value. So just as you have checked for "_" in the diagonal conditions, you should check for it in the row and column if-statement.

This shows the contents of the empty grid array:

[image: screenshot]

Also, you should indent your code to make it easier to read and debug. I would also suggest making a method to print the grid rather than having duplicate nested for-loops to print it.

Answer (score 0):

### Some changes

- I modified the `gameOver()` method which apparently was the problem:
  practically you didn't pass the current grid but you created
  always a new one, therefore, trivially the control is distorted.
- I fixed the *while-loop* by replacing the boolean variable `playing`
  with the simple "break" method: this means that if player 1 wins then
  it immediately exits the cycle;
- I improved insertion;
- I have created a very convenient method that saves you every time to
  write a for to show the grid: `showGrid()`

---

### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // GRID set up
        int SIDE = 3;
        char[][] grid = new char[SIDE][SIDE];
        for (int row = 0; row < SIDE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < SIDE; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = '_';
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            showGrid(grid, SIDE);
            System.out.println("Player1: Please enter row coordinate for your move");
            int row1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Player1: Please enter column coordinate *for-loop* your move");
            int col1 = input.nextInt();
            grid[row1 - 1][col1 - 1] = 'x';
            if (gameOver(grid, row1 - 1, col1 - 1)) {
                showGrid(grid, SIDE);
                System.out.println("Game Over");
                break;
            }
            showGrid(grid, SIDE);
            System.out.println("Player2: Please enter row coordinate for your move");
            int row2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Player2: Please enter column coordinate for your move");
            int col2 = input.nextInt();
            grid[row2 - 1][col2 - 1] = 'O';
            if (gameOver(grid, row1 - 1, col1 - 1)) {
                showGrid(grid, SIDE);
                System.out.println("Game Over");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean gameOver(char[][] grid, int rMove, int cMove) {
        if (grid[0][cMove] == grid[1][cMove]
                && grid[0][cMove] == grid[2][cMove])
            return true;
        if (grid[rMove][0] == grid[rMove][1]
                && grid[rMove][0] == grid[rMove][2])
            return true;
        //Check diagonal victory
        if (grid[0][0] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][0] == grid[2][2]
                && grid[1][1] != '_')
            return true;
        if (grid[0][2] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][2] == grid[2][0]
                && grid[1][1] != '_')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void showGrid(char[][] grid, int side) {
        for (int row = 0; row < side; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < side; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%3c", grid[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%n");
        }
    }
```

Remember that the methods name is always with the *camel case*.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(playing){
            System.out.println ("Player1: Please enter coordinates for your move");
            int row1 = input.nextInt();
            int col1 = input.nextInt();
            grid[row1-1][col1-1] = 'x';
            if (!GameOver(row1-1, col1-1)) {
                playing = false;
                System.out.println("Game Over");
            }


            for (int row = 0; row < SIDE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < SIDE; col++) {
                    System.out.printf("%3c", grid [row][col]);
                }
                System.out.printf("%n");
            }
            System.out.println ("Player 2: Please enter coordinates for your move");
            int row2 = input.nextInt();
            int col2 = input.nextInt();
            grid[row2-1][col2-1] = 'O';
            if (!GameOver(row1-1, col1-1)) {
                playing = false;
                System.out.println("Game Over");
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < SIDE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < SIDE; col++) {
                    System.out.printf("%3c", grid [row][col]);
                }
                System.out.printf("%n");
            }
```